# Recyclerview - cardview onclick change image?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onclick, android-cardview

I have an app that as a Recyclerview --> Cardview, in the cardvie I have text and an image, and what i'm trying to do is to onclick change the 
image of the cardview;

this is the code that handles the click for the card view;
is there a way to change the img on click, recyclerview has around 20 cardviews.

Activity

```
   @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        myAdapter click = myList.get(position);
        String name = click.getName();

        Log.e(TAG, "Position: " + position);
    }
```

Adapter

```
public class ViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView fId;
        public TextView fName; 
        public ImageView fImageButton;

        public ViewHolder2(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            fId       = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id);
            fName     = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            fImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.micd_item_icon); 

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        fListener.onItemClick(position);
                        Log.e(TAG, "D");
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    }



     public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        myAdapter currentItem = myList.get(position);

        String id       = currentItem.getfId();
        String name     = currentItem.getfName(); 

        holder.fId.setText(id);
        holder.fName.setText(name);  
        holder.fImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_cloud_download); 
    }
```

Comment: So you want to change the image in the CardView whenever the CardView is clicked?

Comment: @VedprakashWagh Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Give ID to your `CardView` in your layout.
2. Make a `findViewById()` call in your `ViewHolder`.
3. In `onBindViewHolder` of your `RecyclerView.Adapter`, set an `OnClickListener` to the `CardView`.
4. In `onClick(View v)` of this `CardView`, set the image to ImageView.

   //If you're loading image from list
   Glide.with(context).load(list.get(position).getImageUrl()).into(holder.imageView);

   //If you just want to set an image from your drawables
   holder.imageView.setImageResource(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));

I'm **unable to format** the above stuff properly because **editor is bugged out for me** for some reason.

**Edits are welcome.**

Comment: Thank you for helping me....the clicks has to be on 
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position)

Comment: Yeah so you can handle clicks in onBindViewHolder

Comment: if I add  CardView cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.list); to my onBIndHolder i get an error: findViewById - cannot be resolve

Comment: You don't have to add findViewById in onBindViewHolder, you've to add it in your ViewHolder below super(itemView), and find it as CardView cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.yourCardViewId)